# Security issues with allowing anonymous users to create SQL Server login and accounts?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a rich client program installed on users PCs where I want to start storing some user created data on SQL Azure/SQL Server.   The potential anonymous-to-me users would key in their name, email account and a password which would get stored on SQL Azure/SQL Server.  Then they would start generating their own data.  I'm anticipating volumes of maybe 1000 users.

There are times when those users would like to run their own queries against their own data but, obviously, I must ensure that they can never view other users data.

I'm thinking the best way to ensure security of data is for each user to be issued their own SQL Azure account and password.   I will setup a SQL Azure user and long password, known only to me, which only has permissions to execute several stored procedures with appropriate parameters being passed to those SPs which will create the SQL Server accounts, logins and add the users to a role which I have created.

Obviously someone running debugging tools could figure out the user name and password but I'm thinking this isn't a big deal.  If all that particular SQL Azure account can do is execute a few SPs so what if a malicious individual starts doing that.  I will only allow a very limited amount of data to be uploaded before I require payment.

The users can only insert records using stored procedures which use the following:

```
SELECT @uName=SYSTEM_USER
```

and only select appropriate parent records.  All stored procedures which users can execute would have the above as required to ensure they can only work with their own records.

All views will have embedded with them WHERE clauses such as

```
WHERE tbLoginName = SYSTEM_USER.
```

I'm new to SQL Server so I may be missing some fundamental concepts so I'd appreciate any and all comments.

Comment: Any limitations on the queries folks might choose to run?  Only `SELECT`s?  Or can they `DROP`, `TRUNCATE`, ... ?

Comment: The queries folks would see would be views that I would allow them to see which would only be SELECTs.   No DROPs, TRUNCATEs or such.   That said they'd also be able to see stored procedures that would enable them to insert records of course.  Which, if they wanted to, they could execute but they would only screw up their own data.   The would not be able to see the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, as pointed out on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx:

In SQL Azure, only the server-level principal login (created by the provisioning process) or members of the loginmanager database role in the master database can create new logins.

Those accounts are also capable of alter and drop logins. So if you embed those accounts in the client application, you’re essentially granting every user permission to alter/drop other users accounts. While an average user won’t do that, a hacker will. So you cannot let a client application manage SQL Azure logins, unless only trusted users (such as your IT administrator) are permitted to use the app.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: Hmm, you do have a point there and I should think about that for a bit.  Which is the same for SQL Server and SQL Azure.  That said I can easily just have the new user create a few records in the tables using an SP and display a form telling the new user that I have to manually create the SQL Server account.    I was thinking of having them send me a confirming email anyhow.    So if I do indeed decide to go that route can you see any problem with having a thousand SQL Azure logins?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out a potential issue in the approach you mentioned: Your master SQL Azure account need to have privilege to create new accounts and grant them access to particular tables. This means your master account itself need to also have access to all those tables. If you store the master account on the client side, a clever user will get access to all users data.

From my experience, connecting to a database directly from a client side application will almost always make your solution less secure. You can do that for testing purposes, but in a real world solution, I would like to suggest you to use a service. You can host the service in Windows Azure. Then the service will access the database, and client application can only access the service. In this way, you can authenticate clients using any mechanisms you like, such as ASP.NET membership.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: The master account, meaning my account that gives me full access to all SQL Server objects similar to sa, will never be part of the client exe.   A very limited SQL Server account which can only create SQL Server accounts, change roles and access several stored procedures will be in the client side application.

Comment: But why not use SQL Azure directly?   Why use a service when I don't need it?  Why go through all the extra layers and coding when SQL Azure/SQL Server authentication, along with encryption and SSL will do the job?  Finally why would ASP.Net membership be more secure?

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially creating a physical two-tier database connection, allowing a client application to connect directly to the database. This is a problem in many ways, including security and performance. From a security standpoint, not controlling from where your customers will connect, you will need to keep your firewall rule wide open for anyone in the world to try to hack every customer uid/pwd. And instead of having only 1 user id to play with, hackers will have up to 1,000...

The second issue is performance. You applications will be unable to leverage connection pooling, creating undue stress on your database server and possibly hitting throttling issues at some point. Using a web service, with ASP.NET membership to manage logins, and using a service account (i.e. the same uid/pwd) to get data will ensure you will leverage connection pooling correctly if you keep the connection string the same for all your requests.

With a web service layer you also have a whole slew of new options at your fingertips that a two-tier architecture can't offer. This includes centralizing your business and data access logic, adding caching for improved performance, adding auditing in a centralized location, allowing to make updates to parts of your applications without redeploying anything at your customer locations and so much more...

In the cloud, you are much better off leveraging web services.

My 2 cents.

Comment: As far as security goes well that's how SQL Azure works.  It's wide open to the world.   Hacking, well, the hackers can hack against 1000 user ids on a web services side or 1000 user ids on SQL Azure/SQL Server so what's the difference there?    Connection pooling I don't know much about so I'll have to check that out.   I'm also not too worried about the performance part.  I'm being somewhat vague but basically each user will download maybe three records ten times a day at the most.   Once a week or month at random intervals they might download 10K records in a single burst.

Comment: Now as far as centralizing my business and data access logic well that's all part of my rich client which will be updated as required on the client PC.  Why should I have half my business logic in the rich client and the other half on the web service?   A lot more work to develop and debug.   I also know how to do databases very well in my rich client.

Comment: In regards to connection pooling I don't see the difference between making ten connections pulling three records down per day from a web service vs from SQL Server.  It's the same traffic one way or the other so what does it matter?

Comment: On the security aspect, you are incorrect. SQL Azure is NOT open to the world, unless you open it. Your architecture does that. With web services you have more options to secure your endpoints, including certificates, access control service and so on.

Comment: On managing updates to your code, it depends on how you deploy your solution, and how many clients you have deployed. In some cases the client application can be hard to access for upgrades. I have seen cases where client apps were deployed over hundreds of machines, and upgrades on the client machines were time consuming. Unless you have a very small deployment footprint, placing some, or all of your business logic in web services (which is more centralized by definition) can ease the deployment of upgrades. It may not apply in your case.

Comment: On connection pooling, if you are only making 3 connections per day, then it's not an issue.

Comment: True, SQL Azure is not open to the world by default.   However in my case I would open it up to all IP addresses.     All updates to my app will be managed by my app. That is it will check for updates and update itself as appropriately.   My "install" footprint consists of a single exe with no admin installs required.  Currently it's a download zip file, unzip, drag and drop "install".  If you can call that an install.  :)

Comment: As far as certificates go SQL Azure requires an encrypted connection and optionally SSL certs.  So that will help a lot with security.   Sure someone can try to bruteforce an attack.  But I suspect MS would shut them down after a some attempts.  And even if they do snag one particular account because of my use of SYSTEM_USER in all user accessible queries and SPs they will only ever be able to see that users data.

Comment: BTW their data isn't that confidential.  That is there won't be any personally identifiable information, names, phone numbers or such.